# How to change a+bi form data to complex value in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

my excel file is consist of

[image: many a+bi form data]

How to change all of them to complex form in excel?

like

'1+3i' to '=complex(1,3)'

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can actually extract the real and imaginary parts of a complex number string if it follows the a + bi format without necessarily having to convert every cell to a complex value, it that's what you need to proceed. [More info](https://engineerexcel.com/complex-numbers-in-excel/) about complex functions.

Comment: The format isn't clear because your data is truncated; from your description, I would expect you can nest `Left()`, `Find()`, `Len()`, and `Mid()` inside `Complex()` ... This might get you close `=Complex(Left(A1, Find("+",A1)-1),Mid(A1, Find("+",A1)+1,Len(A1)-Find("+",A1)-1))`

Comment: Why do you even want to do that? The result of the formula `=complex(1,3) would be 1+3i` (your original string). What are you trying to accomplish? In other words `"1+3i" = COMPLEX(IMREAL("1+3i"),IMAGINARY("1+3i"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula

```
=COMPLEX(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("+",A1)-1),SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("+",A1)),"i",""))
```

in `B2` to convert text for the `COMPLEX`-function.

[image]